# unicodedata.normalize is missing one character doing conversion

Tags: python, unicode, unicode-normalization

I'm trying to rename files using the below script, but I'm having problems with catching the following "Don’t" which should end up as "Don't". Any ideas on how I can do this?

```py
def remove_accents(s): 
    nkfd_form = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s) 
    return u''.join([c for c in nkfd_form if not unicodedata.combining(c)])

for fname in glob.glob("**/*.mp3", recursive=True):
    new_fname = remove_accents(fname)
    if new_fname != fname:
        try:
            print ('renaming non-ascii filename to', new_fname)
            os.rename(fname, new_fname)
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong tool for the job - [`unicodedata.normalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) is not about removing accents at all.

For down-converting to ascii, look instead at [`unidecode`](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/):

```
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> unidecode("Don’t")
"Don't"
```

Comment: But isn't the first accent a character that that should be picked up by the normalize and turned in to a normal " ' " like the rest of the latin characters that its changing correctly?

Comment: @Gromit, no it isn't. Like wim said, it's not about removing (or replacing) the accents. The documentation (direct link provided in above answer) explains what the method does: simply said, it makes sure that the characters that *look* the same are *encoded* the same, which makes (binary) comparison easier. For example, `'\u00c7' == '\u0043\u0327'` is False, but if you print both strings, they look the same. The following does return True: `unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', '\u00c7') == unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', '\u0043\u0327')`. But this method is not useful for your application.